# ogr2ogr Error in batch file but works when run from command line

Tags: ogr2ogr, batch, windows-7

If I run this from the command line it works:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\bin\ogr2ogr.exe" -f GeoJSON d:\environprocessing\q3_2015\wi\brrts\GISRegistry_Offsite1.geojson "http://dnrmaps.wi.gov/arcgis/rest/services/RR_Sites_Map/RR2_GIS_Registry_WTM_Ext/MapServer/3/query?where=objectid+%3C+1000&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=objectid&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&f=pjson" OGRGeoJSON -gt 1000
```

But If I put it into a batch file and run it from the very same command line instance I get the following error:

```
ERROR 4: Failed to read GeoJSON data
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `http://dnrmaps.wi.gov/arcgis/rest/servicesRR_Sites_Map/RR2_GIS_Registry_WTM_Ext/MapServer/3/query?where=objectid+C+1000&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=objectid&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&f=pjson' with the following drivers.
-> OCI
-> SOSI
-> ESRI Shapefile
-> MapInfo File
-> GeoJSON
... lists many more here, you get the idea ...
```

Why the difference?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but does anything change if you prepend your url with `/vsicurl/`, like this: `/vsicurl/http://dnrmaps.wi.gov/arcgis/rest..` ?

Comment: Or ..maybe the trouble has to do with [URL-encoded characters in the batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files)?

Comment: @elrobis, Darn, I tried both separately and together, but no joy.

Comment: Good to know. Some flags in the ogr2ogr command are definitely getting interpreted, so my gut feeling is there must be something "off" about how the batch interpreter sees the URL text/string. ..one more thought, try reversing the slashes, like `http:\\dnrmaps.wi.gov\arcgis\rest..` ?

Comment: Ahh perhaps confirming my gut feeling ^, if you look at your command line url and the url noted in your error message side-by-side, I'm seeing some differences, most notably `/servicesRR_Sites_Map/` vs. `/services/RR_Sites_Map/` ..see the missing slash in the error message from the batch file?? I betcha that's your gremlin. ;)

Answer (score 2):

With some help from @elrobis I tracked down the cause of the problem and a simple solution. If you have a percent sign (%) in the batch file (as a result of URL Encoding non alphanumeric characters) it is interpreted as a variable name - see [this oldy but goody of an article](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/using-urls-batch-files).

Since the variable replacements are happening before the batch file is executed, surrounding the URL in quotes has no bearing.

You can either un-URL Encode the special characters like changing **where=objectid+%3C+1000** to **where=objectid+>+1000** (%3C is the URL encoded version of the larger than sign >), or you can escape the % with another % like **where=objectid+%%3C+1000**.